# How to use anchor tag to find a fixed position in the current jsp in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I just want to location my html tag in my current jsp page,it means that I do not need to jump to the controller.Now I use the code,but it always jump to the controller,how to change my code?
My website url is `http://localhost:8888/MySpringMVC/`,and I have a div called `headdiv` in the top.When user click the link,I want to locate it to the `headdiv`.My current web page url is `http://localhost:8888/MySpringMVC/main/index`. I want to jump to `http://localhost:8888/MySpringMVC/main/index#top-container`

```
<!--both of ways  jump to http://localhost:8888/MySpringMVC/#top-container-->
<a href="javascript:void(window.location.href='#top-container')">
<a href="#top-container">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second thing you tried should work (`<a href="#top-container">TEST</a>`), works in my tests which means there is probably more to it than you wrote in your question.

Anyway, here is a small javascript solution that should work

```
<a href="" onclick="window.location.hash = 'top-container'; return false;">TEST</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<a href="#top-container" onClick="return false;">`

Comment: I find the link url is  always `http://localhost:8888/MySpringMVC/#top-container`,how to change it ?